# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'activeWord' on number '0'

Tags: reactjs, redux

in my react application, i have pre-loaded a reducer called `activeWord`.

```
activeWord: 0
```

Then i have added the `activeWord` in the root reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import activeWord from './ActiveWordReducer';

const root_reducer=combineReducers({

    activeWord:activeWord
});

export default root_reducer;
```

And then in `ActiveWordReducer` file:

```
export default function WordReducer(state=null,action){
    switch(action.type){
      case "Active_Word":
        return state.activeWord++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, in the line `state.activeWord++`, it generates an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'activeWord' on number '0'
```

So how can i fix this issue?

**Update**:

in the reducer i also tried to return state but still i got the same error:

```
export default function WordReducer(state=null,action){
    switch(action.type){
      case "Active_Word":
        return state.activeWord++;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: I believe your `state` is already `activeWord` itself, so you just need to do `state++`

Comment: Because reducers get a sliced states, not the whole one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems that I would like to mention:

- Function `combineReducers` takes an object, where key is the name of the reducer function and the value is the name of the property of state that should be passed to that reducer. So, for your case, it should be like,

  `const root_reducer = combineReducers({ activeWord: activeWord });`

  But, if its the case that you've a reducer called `activeWord` which ultimately calls that `WordReducer`, then please ignore this suggestion. And maybe, you'd like to rename `WordReducer` to `wordReducer`.
- In your `WordReducer` function, `state` now represents `activeWord`. So, it's just a number. That's why you are getting that error.
- Do not mutate your object. Just return `state + 1`. And keep constant all caps.

So, your reducer should look like,

`export default function WordReducer(state = 0, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case "ACTIVE_WORD":
        return state + 1;
      default:
        return state;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your reducer returns 0 as a state.

When the app state is initialized, all reducers are called. Because of `WordReducer` that returns`0`, `ActiveWordReducer` default state is `0`.

If you trigger the action `Active_Word`, your want to read `activeWord` on `ActiveWordReducer` state. But that is not possible because the state is `0`. It is like doing `0.activeWord`. The solution is to do:

```
var defaultState = {activeWord : 0};

export default function WordReducer(state=defaultState ,action){
  switch(action.type){
    case "Active_Word":
      return state.activeWord++;
  }
  return state;
}
```

As a result, if the state in your reducer is not initialized yet, it will create a state `{activeWord : 0}`

Keep in mind that your reducer must ALWAYS return the `state` parameter if there is not any `action.type` that matches your switch cases.

Comment: I have returend the **state**, also removed the preloading part and set **var defaultState = {activeWord : 0};
** but still get the same error after 1 action?

Comment: when debugging on line `return state.activeWord++;`, how `state` looks like?

Comment: Object {activeWord: 0}